# Printing an XML file from DataFrame python with condition

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have a pandas `df` like this:

```
ID  EpisodeID  Origin   Destination
1      1         A          B
1      2         B          A
2      1         C          D
2      2         D          E
2      3         E          C
3      1         A          D
3      2         D          A
```

I want to make a txt file with this `df` as source. Therefore, I'm using a code such as this:

```
with open("output.txt","w+") as f:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        f.write("  <person id =\"%s\">\n" % (row['ID']))
        f.write("     <activity  O=\"%s"\   D=\"%s"\>\n % (row[Origin], row[Destination]))
        f.write("     </activity>\n")
        f.write("  </person>\n")
```

the output shows something like:

```
<person id="1">
   <activity O="A"  D="B">
   </activity>
</person>
<person id="1">
   <activity O="B"  D="A">
   </activity>
</person>
```

However, what I'm trying to make is not like this. How can I iterate or write the code so that the output will be something like:

```
<person id="1">
   <activity O="A"  D="B">
   </activity>
   <activity O="B"  D="A">
   </activity>
</person>
<person id="2">
   <activity O="C"  D="D">
   </activity>
   <activity O="D"  D="E">
   </activity>
   <activity O="E"  D="C"
   </activity>
</person>
```

So, what I'm trying to make  for each ID, not for all index (if that makes any sense).

Please help :)

Comment: Group by ID; then while iterating the groups build the string. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a nested loop, group by `ID` column first and write the `person` tag for each group and within each group, loop and write the `activity`:

```
with open("output.txt","w+") as f:
    for _id, g in df.groupby('ID'):
        f.write(f'  <person id ="{_id}">\n')
        for t in g.itertuples():  # use itertuples since it's faster than iterrows
            f.write(f'     <activity  O="{t.Origin}" D="{t.Destination}">\n')
            f.write("     </activity>\n")
        f.write("  </person>\n")
```

Output:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    print(''.join(f.readlines()))
```

---

```
  <person id ="1">
     <activity  O="A" D="B">
     </activity>
     <activity  O="B" D="A">
     </activity>
  </person>
  <person id ="2">
     <activity  O="C" D="D">
     </activity>
     <activity  O="D" D="E">
     </activity>
     <activity  O="E" D="C">
     </activity>
  </person>
  <person id ="3">
     <activity  O="A" D="D">
     </activity>
     <activity  O="D" D="A">
     </activity>
  </person>
```